# MySQL Workbench reports "select is not valid at this position for this server version , expecting FOR,LOCK,TABLE, VALUES, With,'(' "

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

**When implementing a basic CASE WHEN statement in MySQL Workbench, I am getting the following error "SELECT is not valid at this position for this server version. Expecting FOR, LOCK, TABLES, VALUES, WITH, '('".**

Here is my SQL query:

```
select staff_id , salary,
case when salary >=10000 then 'high salary'
when salary between 5000 and 10000 then 'Average salary'
when salary<5000 then 'Too Low'
end as Range
from staff_salary;
```

Answer (score 0):

`range` is a reserved word in MySQL, and should not be used.

so rename it

```
select staff_id , salary,
case when salary >=10000 then 'high salary'
when salary between 5000 and 10000 then 'Average salary'
when salary<5000 then 'Too Low'
end as Range1
from staff_salary;
```

or use Backticks

```
select staff_id , salary,
case when salary >=10000 then 'high salary'
when salary between 5000 and 10000 then 'Average salary'
when salary<5000 then 'Too Low'
end as `Range`
from staff_salary;
```